# "rails s" and "rake db:migrate" returning errors such as warning: circular argument reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I'm trying to start up a rails project from a git repo. I have already `bundle install`ed without any errors, and have the correct versions of Ruby (2.2.4) and Rails (4.1.9) that are specified in the `Gemfile`. When I try to start up the rails server using `rails s` on bash (Ubuntu), I get:

```
    /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/lib/compass/core/caniuse.rb:72: warning: circular argument reference - browsers
/home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/fog-1.19.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:150: warning: circular argument reference - filters
/home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/fog-1.19.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:43: warning: duplicated key at line 81 ignored: "name"
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
Could not load database configuration. No such file - 
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from /home/name/Documents/RAdrive2/drive2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/name/Documents/RAdrive2/drive2/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/name/Documents/RAdrive2/drive2/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/name/Documents/RAdrive2/drive2/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@drive2/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Pretty much the same thing happens when I do `rake db:migrate`. What happened here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the commands as a super user: sudo bundle install and sudo rails server

Comment: While rails s works, sudo rails s gives me sudo: rails: command not found...additionially, as I wrote before, bundle install worked fine.